# Imported data doesn't list the date and time in correct order

Tags: sql-server, date

Hi in my MSSQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2008 product, the table I imported data into, doesn't list the DATES and TIME in the correct order , where i do queries i want the dates to list in correct orders .  At Present this is how the date and times are listed when i do query:

```
 and (date >= '2000-02-27 17:15:00' and date <= '2000-03-27 17:15:00')

2000-03-19 14:00:00 , 
2000-03-19 14:30:00 , 
2000-03-19 15:00:00 , 
2000-03-19 15:30:00 ,
2000-03-04 14:00:00 , 
2000-03-04 14:30:00 , 
2000-03-04 15:05:00 , 
2000-03-17 14:20:00 ,
2000-03-17 14:50:00 , 
2000-03-17 15:20:00 ,
2000-03-17 15:50:00
```

Comment: try `order by` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: MySQL or MSSQL ? Confusion here. Management Studio 2008 is for MSSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use ORDER BY clause?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (date >= '2000-02-27 17:15:00' and date <= '2000-03-27 17:15:00') 
ORDER BY date DESC
```